# Python Pandas - Multiple assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an efficient way to make the following assignment without using for loops?

```
for i in range(0,len(df3)):
    if df3.loc[i,'field'] == "a":
        df3.loc[i,'field'] = "111"
    elif df3.loc[i, 'field'] == "b":
        df3.loc[i, 'field'] = "222"
    elif df3.loc[i, 'field'] == "c":
        df3.loc[i, 'field'] = "333"
    else:
        df3.loc[i,'field'] = "444"
```

Comment: why are you changing `field` in the last three `elif`, but `a` in the first? A typo?

Comment: For starters if you just did this `df3.loc[df['field']=='a','field'] = '111'` and so on you wouldn't need to iterate at all just call `loc` like above 4 times

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the example of the data frame you start with and the data frame that you want to end with

Comment: Anand, thank you for pointing out the typo, i have modified my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the code, but you still need a loop to hop through the df3 structure and hit all your "field" fields.

```
xlate = {'a':'111', 'b':'222', 'c':'333'}
for i in range(len(df3)):
    df3.loc[i, 'field'] = xlate.get(df3.loc[i, 'field'], '444')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
 df3.loc[df.field == 'a', 'field'] = '111'
```

and so on...